# Sorting grails list based off of string from a linked table

Tags: grails

I've got two domains, one stored a link to another, like so (I've cut out all the other fields to eliminate noise): -

```
class TestScenario {
    static constraints = {
        testscenariodesc(blank:false, maxSize:100, unique: true)
    }

static mapping = {
    table "test_scenario"
    version false
    columns{
        id column:"test_scenario_id"
    }
}

String testscenariodesc

String toString(){
    "${testscenariodesc}"
}
}
```

This is used in: -

```
class TestExecQueue {
    static constraints = {
        testscenarioid()
        myPriority(inList:[0,1,2,3,4], blank:false)
    }

static mapping = {
    table "test_exec_queue"
    version false
    columns{
        id column:"test_exec_queue_id"
        testscenarioid column:"test_scenario_id"
        myPriority column:"Priority"
    }
}

TestScenario testscenarioid
Integer myPriority
}
```

I've got a list in my testexecqueue like so: -

```
 def list(Integer max) {
        params.max = 10000
        [testExecQueueInstanceList: TestExecQueue.list(params), testExecQueueInstanceTotal: TestExecQueue.count()]

    }
```

But what I want to do is return the results sorted by the testscenariodesc value (not the numeric value of testscenarioID.  Is this possible?

I tried this: -

```
[testExecQueueInstanceList: TestExecQueue.list(params, sort: "testscenarioid", order: "desc"), testExecQueueInstanceTotal: TestExecQueue.count()]
```

But when I then go to the page I get the following error:

```
No signature of method: testautomation.TestExecQueue.list() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[sort:testscenarioid, order:desc], [action:list, ...]] Possible solutions: list(), last(), list(java.util.Map), first(), last(java.lang.String), last(java.util.Map)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks for any suggestions! :)

Answer (score 0):

The list() method accepts `sort` and `order` parameters. Take a look at the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) for details. For example

```
def results = myDomain.list([max: 10, sort: 'myColumn', order: 'asc'])
```

Alternatively you can specify a default sort order on your domain. For example:

```
class MyClass {
  String myColumn
  static mapping = {
    sort 'myColumn'
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the sort but doesnt seem to work, have updated with example of code

Comment: In your code you will need to add to the params map instead of passing another parameter to the list method. e.g. before your list() call use params.sort = 'testscenarioid'

Comment: Do you mean just use `params.max = 10000
  params.sort = 'testscenarioid'
  [testExecQueueInstanceList: TestExecQueue.list(params), testExecQueueInstanceTotal: TestExecQueue.count()]`  That doesn't seem to do anything (will it sort on the numeric ID value or the equivalent string value that it links to and returns?)